# Where would computer/industry related subjective discussion questions go?

Tags: discussion, questions, subjective

Where would questions like this go?
https://superuser.com/questions/98849/why-does-wikipedia-work-closed

Comment: Forums​​​​​​​​.

Comment: As long as it's not SuperUser...

Answer (score 3):

On very general forums, like [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/).

Just because wikipedia is accessed through a computer, doesn't make it computer related.  The referenced question also is a discussion question, which is not what the SO-family sites are built for.

Answer (score 2):

From the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts
>   and power users. If you have a
>   question ... and it is not about ...
>
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
>
> ...
>
> then you're in the right place to ask
>   your question!

Additionally:

> Avoid asking questions that are
>   subjective, argumentative, or require
>   extended discussion.

Given those guidelines (the second of which applies universally to the Trilogy, and frankly to many of the StackExchange sites as well), this question and others of its ilk explicitly don't belong on the Trilogy sites.

Just because we have 3 buckets (4 if you count Meta) doesn't mean we have a place to address every question about anything technical on the planet.

Your discussion may well have merit, but it is not a good fit for SuperUser, nor frankly any of the Trilogy sites. It's much better being discussed in a blog post or on a general purpose discussion board/forum.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the **Other/General** category in this list:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions