# Where can I ask a question that demands different opinions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Stack Overflow doesn't really support questions that do not have a specific answer, such as "What are the features you would want in a programming language that are lacked by most programming languages?". Is there a Stack Exchange site or other external site specifically made for this?

Comment: No. The policy is the same all across the network as far as I know.

Comment: What use would the answer have to you? The answer to that question is whatever you should be asking

Comment: Anyone who devoted this is a coward.

Comment: @opatachibueze On Meta downvotes indicate disagreement. Please review the FAQ to understand how voting works here.

Comment: @opatachibueze And after you read the part on what voting means on Meta, please read the the part on [etiquette](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette). Name calling is not very nice, and it won't help you get answers to your questions...

Comment: @Diago: That's my point, 5 downvotes with only one person addressing my question and two comments speaking off-point or without thinking. Like "what use would the answer have to you?" So it's likely I'm a dumb person?.. who wastes his time online asking questions..a silly comment, with 3 upvotes.

Comment: @YannisRizos I don't see why people should be taking my questions personal.

Comment: Voting works differently on Meta. see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences subjective discussions were allowed much more leeway in the early days of the site, and it was found (rightly or wrongly) that overall, they lower the quality of the content on the site. This discussion has been had a number of times already and at the moment, it doesn't seem like the consensus is likely to change.

Comment: While the main SE sites are for Q&A only, you can participate in open-ended discussions with other programmers in the SE [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I don't see why people should be taking *downvotes* personally. Care to explain that one?

Comment: If you can manage to ask a [good subjective question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) that's on topic for a site, then go for it.  But its not that easy, and you might find your question being shot down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for subjective answers to my questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94937/looking-for-subjective-answers-to-my-questions)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where would computer/industry related subjective discussion questions go?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36487/where-would-computer-industry-related-subjective-discussion-questions-go), [Where can I ask questions that aren't Stack Overflow questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally decided the only person that really answered my question was [@Pekka in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126110/where-can-i-ask-a-question-that-demands-different-opinions#comment341282_126113):

> Objective, answerable questions are at the core of SO's concept. Would
> you walk into a factory that has been building cars successfully for
> fifty years and tell them that they need to start building trucks
> because trucks are useful? There are many other places (like Quora)
> that work more in the way you desire; do check them out. Web sites are
> not real life; the are virtual communities of people with different
> dynamics

And to add to his answer, one of my friend told me he asks such questions on a typical forum/message board. So I guess I'll be going for that option. Thanks to everyone who really tried to help.

Answer (score 11):

The "What are the features you would want in a programming language that are lacked by most programming languages?" question isn't really suitable for Stack Exchange, it's a poll for opinions rather than a question on an actual practical problem. It's not a bad question, it just doesn't work with the Q&A format of Stack Exchange, as there is no sensible way of vetting answers.

We welcome *some* subjective questions on [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), however your question would most likely be closed as "not constructive".

Further reading:

- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Real Questions Have Answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)
- [Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: In the real (social) world, when you ask a question you are entitled to select (vetting) the answers you need yourself. I have seen very useful questions that have been closed on StackOverFlow like list of free computer science textbooks, etc. In my own case for example, I'm writing a language which I want to have some major features missed by many others, however picking out these features bit by bit is tiring when people usually already have them at the back of their minds. So I don't see why StackExchange shouldn't support it.

Comment: @opatachibueze Stack Exchange has a very specific format, not _every_ real world question fits its mechanics, read the two blog posts I've linked to for more details. You can obviously evaluate the answers yourself, however we expect questions to be of use to a wider audience, not just the asker.

Comment: of course I do understand, I am just trying to say that I don't think that's the best way to go about it. The answer selection and upvotes makes it easier for external users to easily sort or get the best answers and the network can easily be modified to hide downvoted answers by default, etc. You shouldn't cut someone's hand to help a bleeding person.

Comment: @opatachibueze The problem with your question is that there is no actual problem to be solved, and up / down votes won't make much sense, since there aren't enough parameters to decide whether an answer sufficiently answers the question. People can add features ad nauseam and all answers are equally valid. Again: Not a bad question, however not a Stack Exchange question.

Comment: I think you're simply refusing to see it in a real life sense. Opinions which many people agree with will get upvotes and non-making sense/unuseful opinions will get downvotes. And that should equally be useful to everyone. Just like in the example question I mentioned

Comment: @opatachibueze Objective, answerable questions are at the core of SO's concept. Would you walk into a factory that has been building cars successfully for fifty years and tell them that they need to start building trucks because trucks are useful? There are many other places (like Quora) that work more in the way you desire; do check them out. Web sites are not real life; the are virtual communities of people with different dynamics

Comment: Yes you are free to suggest to them that building trucks is useful. It's their choice to accept or discard your opinion. I also don't believe that if allowing this hasn't worked so far, then it's best to discard it. Problems are meant to be solved and as far as I know, StackOverFlow has the largest community of programming enthusiasts. I just signed up to Quora and was welcomed with unanswered questions asked by my friends.